# Android RemoteView textStyle bold

Tags: android, textview, widget, xamarin, remoteview

This issue is related to an android widget written in `C#` using `Xamarin`.

I want to set a textview's `text style` to `bold` for an element of my widget layout. Changing the text itself works well but I can't set other attributes.

This is the part of the method which builds the update

```
remoteViews.SetTextViewText(Resource.Id.widget_info, nextItemText[1]);
if (element.InProgress)
{
    // this is my try to set textstyle to bold
    remoteViews.SetString(Resource.Id.widget_info, "textStyle", "bold");
}
```

How can I set the `text style` to `bold`?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7):

I don't know about Xamarin/C#, but this is how you would do it in Java, maybe you can adapt it:

```
SpannableString s = new SpannableString("To boldly go where no man has gone before"); 
// make the word "boldly" be in bold
s.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 3, 9, 0); 
remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.txt, s);
```